# Change Button Background when is not enabled

Tags: c#, wpf, button, disabled-control

I need to change my `Button` background (as SolidColorBrush for example) only when it is not enabled (`IsEnabled == false`).
 How can I do?

Have I to modify the Button `Style` using the XAML or can I do this work programmatically? What is the correct XAML code, to change only the Background when it is not enabled?

I tried the following XAML code but it has no effect:

```
<Button>
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: check this article: http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2010/07/wpf_-_disabled_look_for_button.html

Comment: why doesn't this work? has anyone got explaination?

Answer (score 7):

You can change the background by editing the template. You'll find the default template for `Button` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In the trigger for `IsEnabled` you can simply add something like this:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
```

**EDIT**:
Try this instead then;

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="Overlay" CornerRadius="2">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Overlay" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Button" IsEnabled="False"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Just change it to suit your needs.

Comment: It is not the default template. Where can I find the correct template?

Comment: What version are you looking for? You can change the version in the top there for other versions.

Comment: I'm looking for de default version. I want to change only the background when my button is disabled. The link that you provided me has a style that changes my button default style. Try yourself..

Comment: I meant .NET version. (ie. 4.0 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.100%29.aspx, ). Try the code I just added instead then, it should work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Style trigger:

```
<Image.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/disabled.png" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Image.Style>
```

Comment: Why Image.Style? I need to change the SolidColorBrush of my Button.

Comment: Use Button.Background instead of Image.Source and set color (or specific brush) in Value